# AES Decryption in VB.NET no longer working for specific PDFs

Tags: vb.net, pdf, encryption, aes

On our web application we have a upload section where you could upload and download PDF files. It would encrypt them on upload and decrypt them on download. It worked fine at first but now several of the files come back corrupted.

Certain PDF files will encrypt and decrypt successfully every time, and certain ones will return corrupted every time. I tried re-testing it with the same PDF file I knew worked before, and it no longer works. So while it seems to be file specific, files that worked before are not necessarily working anymore.

Here is the encryption class I am using:

```
Public Class clsEncryptFile

Public Sub Encrypt(inputFilePath As String, outputfilePath As String)

    Dim EncryptionKey As String = "FAKEKEY"

    Using encryptor As Aes = Aes.Create()

        Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D, &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65, &H76})

        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)

        Using fs As New FileStream(outputfilePath, FileMode.Create)
            Using cs As New CryptoStream(fs, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                Using fsInput As New FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open)
                    Dim data As Integer

                    While (Assign(data, fsInput.ReadByte())) <> -1
                        cs.WriteByte(CByte(data))
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Public Sub Decrypt(inputFilePath As String, outputfilePath As String)
    Dim EncryptionKey As String = "FAKEKEY"
    Using encryptor As Aes = Aes.Create()
        Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D, _
         &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65, _
         &H76})
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)
        Using fs As New FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open)
            Using cs As New CryptoStream(fs, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                Using fsOutput As New FileStream(outputfilePath, FileMode.Create)
                    Dim data As Integer
                    While (Assign(data, cs.ReadByte())) <> -1
                        fsOutput.WriteByte(CByte(data))
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Private Shared Function Assign(Of T)(ByRef source As T, ByVal value As T) As T
    source = value
    Return value
End Function

End Class
```

Here is the sub that encrypts the files(using a telerik radasyncupload event):

```
Private Sub _upWorkPapers_FileUploaded(sender As Object, e As Telerik.Web.UI.FileUploadedEventArgs) Handles _upWorkPapers.FileUploaded
    Dim newfilename As String

    newfilename = Session("Asi_Num") & "_" & _hdnNoteDate.Value.Replace("/", "") '& e.File.GetExtension

    e.File.SaveAs(IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(_upWorkPapers.TargetFolder), newfilename & e.File.GetExtension))

    Dim input As String = Convert.ToString(Server.MapPath("/Repository/WorkPapers/") & newfilename) & e.File.GetExtension
    Dim output As String = Convert.ToString((Server.MapPath("/Repository/WorkPapers/") & newfilename) + "_enc") & e.File.GetExtension

    'Encrypt the file
    'crptFile is declared at top of the class as Dim crptFile As New clsEncryptFile
    crptFile.Encrypt(input, output)

    'Set hidden value to store filename
    _hdnFileName.Value = newfilename
    _hdnFileExtension.Value = e.File.GetExtension

    'Delete Original File
    File.Delete(input)

End Sub
```

And here is the sub that decrypts the file:

```
Protected Sub DownloadFile()
    Dim input As String = Convert.ToString((Server.MapPath("/Repository/WorkPapers/") & _hdnFileName.Value) + "_enc") & _hdnFileExtension.Value
    Dim output As String = Convert.ToString((Server.MapPath("/Repository/WorkPapers/") & _hdnFileName.Value) + "_dec") & _hdnFileExtension.Value
    'crptFile is declared at top of class as Dim crptFile As New clsEncryptFile
    crptFile.Decrypt(input, output)

    ''Download the Decrypted File.
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"


    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(output))
    Response.WriteFile(output)
    Response.Flush()

    'Delete the decrypted (output) file.
    File.Delete(output)

End Sub
```

None of these have changed since it was implemented, but suddenly its functionality is very spotty. Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: How are they corrupted? Are they too short, have extra bytes at the end, or completely jumbled?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Morton I just opened them in notepad and it appears the HTML of the website is being added to the end of the file. Not entirely sure if this is the entire problem yet, but the issue was that PDF viewer said they were damaged. The working ones have this too.

Comment: Please have a look at [When downloading a file from ASP .Net, the text file gets appended with HTML content](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37818354/1115360).

Comment: @AndrewMorton That fixed the problem, thank you very much